# Creating Databricks Database Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, databricks, disaster-recovery

I have a database created in my [Databricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Databricks#Products) environment which is mounted to an [AWS S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) location. Is there a way to take the snapshot of the database so that I can store it to different place and restore it in case of any failure?

Answer (score 1):

Databricks is not like a traditional database where all data is stored "inside" the database. For example, Amazon RDS provides a "snapshot" feature that can dump the entire contents of a database, and the snapshot can then be restored to a new database server if required.

The equivalent in Databricks would be [Delta Lake time travel](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/history.html#query-an-older-snapshot-of-a-table-time-travel), which allows you to **access the database as it was at a previous point-in-time**. Data is not "restored" -- rather, it is simply presented as it previously was at a given timestamp. It is a snapshot without the need to actually create a snapshot.

From [Configure data retention for time travel](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/history.html#configure-data-retention-for-time-travel):

> To time travel to a previous version, you must retain both the log and the data files for that version.
>
> The data files backing a Delta table are never deleted automatically; data files are deleted only when you run VACUUM. VACUUM does not delete Delta log files; log files are automatically cleaned up after checkpoints are written.

If, instead, you do want to keep a "snapshot" of the database, a good method would be to create a **deep clone** of a table, which includes all data. See:

- [CREATE TABLE CLONE | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html)
- [Using Deep Clone for Disaster Recovery with Delta Lake on Databricks](https://www.databricks.com/wp-content/uploads/notebooks/using-deep-clone-disaster-recovery-delta-lake-databricks.html)

I think you would need to write your own script to loop through each table and perform this operation. It is not as simple as clicking the "Create Snapshot" button in Amazon RDS.

Comment: Rotensten - Thank you for the detailed explaination. The purposone of taking snapshot is to implement the disaster recovery. So that If possible I can take snapshot of s3 bucket and export to different region. It may sound silly but I am new to this.

Comment: What "disaster" are you catering for? Each AWS Region consists of multiple Availability Zones. Each AZ is a separate data center. Amazon S3 stores its data across multiple AZs in each region. So, it has in-built High Availability meaning that if a data center fails, the service continues to operate. Yes, you are welcome to replicate the buckets to another region (eg using [S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html)) but that depends on the amount of "Disaster" you are expecting. You would also need to replicate Databricks to another region.